# Why is my program printing the last input line twice?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

My program is supposed to print what my input give reading it letter by
letter with a scanf  and saving them in variables when after they print
whats
inside them. This in a cycle so it can print every line. But it seems it
either is scanning the last line two times or printing it two times

I tried putting \n inside the scans which solve the printing problem but
now it wouldn't print the first letters of each line

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double tempG = 0;
    double altG = 0;
    double humG = 0;

    char cultivo[100] = " ";

    char  nombre[100] = " ";
    double temp = 0;
    double alt = 0;
    double hum = 0;

    char insertado;
    
    int contador = 0;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf" , &tempG, &altG, & humG);
    printf("%2.0lf %2.0lf %2.0lf \n \n", tempG, altG, humG);
    char temporal[100] = "";
    while(scanf("%c", &insertado) != EOF){
            scanf("%s %lf %lf %lf", nombre, &temp, &alt, &hum);
            printf("%s %.0lf %.0lf %.0lf \n", nombre, temp, alt, hum);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is my input and my expected output:

> ```
> 25 65 1200
>
> Banano 27 50 1000
> Brocoli 16 75 2500
> Fresas 18 80 2000
> Zanahoria 21 75 1200
> Tomate 22 75 1000
> ```

This is my actual output:

> ```
> 25 65 1200
>
> Banano 27 50 1000
> Brocoli 16 75 2500
> Fresas 18 80 2000
> Zanahoria 21 75 1200
> Tomate 22 75 1000
> Tomate 22 75 1000
> ```

Comment: I did but it still wont work, still prints it two times

Comment: if I put a space int the scanf after the last %lf it stops printing the last one twice but it stops printing the first letter of each one

Comment: You should always check the return value of every `scanf()` call for success before trying to use the values it sets.

Comment: Kind of new in C so im not sure what you mean but im actually printg them to see if its scanning everything how its supposed to but it seems its not doing that

Comment: Use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read lines, then use `sscanf()` to parse the data.  It often works better — and, in particular, would work better for you.

Comment: Ok thanks ill read into those methods to understand what they do and ill see if they work for me, ill let you know

Answer (score 2):

- `scanf` is reading values into variables that aren't cleared before each run.
- You aren't checking the return value of `scanf` to make sure that it succeeded.
- `scanf` doesn't read the newline at the end of the input, but the `scanf('%c')` does.

Together this means after you read your last line of input, you loop back, `while(scanf(…))` successfully reads in the final newline, your other `scanf` fails because there's no more input, and the `printf` prints the stale data inside the local variables.

Comment: hmm okay so i understand its doing it one more time but then what can I do to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf` before trying to use any of the variables that it was supposed to write into.  After you `scanf` the line, you can use `getc()` to grab the next character and either throw it away if it's a newline, or put it back with `ungetc()` if it's not.  Your `while` condition would then check for EOF instead of trying to read anything.

Comment: Well in the while i also tried to put instead of ==1 i put != EOF but it didnt work either. But ill try using this getc() now and let you know if it works

Comment: ok i tried if getc(stdin) == '\n'   throw away else ungetc(stdin); but this unget is not working

Comment: When you call `ungetc()`, you also have to pass it the character to put back.  See [the ungetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ungetc) documentation for usage details.